# Namespace not found

Tags: c#, interface

I have defined the following code for my interface:

```
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Graphics;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Android.Content.Res;
using MyApp.Droid;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MeasureString))]
namespace MyApp.UWP
{
        public class MeasureString : IMeasureString
        {
            public double calculateWidth(string text)
            {
                    Rect bounds = new Rect();
                    TextView textView = new TextView(Forms.Context);
                    textView.Paint.GetTextBounds(text, 0, text.Length, bounds);
                    var length = bounds.Width();
                    return length / Resources.System.DisplayMetrics.ScaledDensity;
            }
        }
}
```

This is my interface class:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyApp
{
    public interface IMeasureString
    {
        public double calculateWidth(string text);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error "Type or Namespace MeasureString not found". Possible missing using directive or assembly reference".

I thought I'd copied everything over from my template interface which works fine and contains just the same namings.

How would I go on investigation what I'm missing?

Comment: What is `[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MeasureString))]` supposed to do?

Comment: I don't know. I've copied it over from my other interface template.

Comment: You're missing `using MyApp;` since the namespace is different. Your class is in `MyApp.UWP`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attribute is applied outside the `namespace` block, so that class isn't actually in scope.

You can either add a `using` statement for your own namespace or fully qualify the classname.

Comment: I've included "using MyApp.Droid". Now I've also included "using MyApp". Isn't that sufficient? Both usings are not used, they're shown in light gray.

Comment: Thank you!! I've used the wrong "includes". I actually used .Droid in my .UWP project. Thank you!